# Convert List<Map> to List<Object>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a Java class

```
public class ListData extends ArrayList<Object> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ListData() {
        super();
    }

    public ListData(List<Object> list) {
        super(list);
    }

}
```

In another class I have following code

```
List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = toMapList(objects, keys); // Some function returning List<Map>
ListData listData = new ListData(mapList);
```

The Eclipse showing error as

> The constructor `ListData(List<Map<String,Object>>)` is undefined.

Why it's not accepting as `List<Object>`?  and how to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: here's my favorite answer by Jon Skeet http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/4680812

Comment: You have to define the constructor like `public ListData(List<Map<String, Object>> mapList) {`